# Styling with PopupControlExtender

Tags: asp.net, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit

So I have a table, with a row (tr) that has a AJAX toolkit PopupControlExtender. Here is the code -

```
<table id="fixedHeaderTable" border="1" cellspacing="0" runat="server">
    <tr id="headerRowFixedTable" style="height: 82px;" runat="server">
        <span id="lblColumnHeader" runat="server" />
        <img id="imgFilter" alt="Filter" src="../../App_Themes/Images/filter.png" onclick="showFilter('')" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCombo" runat="server" Visible="false" ReadOnly="true" Width="200" Font-Size="X-Small"/>
        <cc1:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender111" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCombo" PopupControlID="Panel111" Position="Top" />
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel111" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto" style="z-index:152; background-color:Gray;" BorderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="1">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkList" runat="server" Height="20"/>
            <asp:Button ID="btnFilter" Text="Filter" runat="server" onclick="btnFilter_Click" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is the PopupControlExtender's height stays within the limits of the table row that is is on. How do I style that control so that when it expands, the expanded panel isn't affected by the limitations of the table row and that it can be bigger (more height) than that row?

Comment: Removing `style="height: 82px;"`?

Comment: Is there a reason it has to be within the table row?

Comment: @Morpheus - removing that style didn't work.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely - Yes, I am trying to build a table filtering function using that popup control extender. (There are distinct values from the table in the resulting chkList)

Comment: I think you're going to run into parent height limiting the panel's height unless you move it outside of the parent.  You may be able to set absolute height and width, but I don't know how that'll end up looking.

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute positioning works.